# Variable with asterisk

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I need to find some image files with`$tempThumb`, but for some reason the following code doesn't work in my bash script, although I tried the same in terminal and it did work

```
randomStr=$(date | md5sum | tr -d ' -')
tempThumb=$(echo "$randomStr _ tempthumb" | tr -d ' ')
ls /dev/shm/$tempThumb*.jpg | sort -t '-' -n -k 2 | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's about shell programming — a limited case, but still shell programming.  And shell programming is on-topic for SO.

Comment: Can you show how you populate $tempThumb?

Comment: What's in `$tempThumb`?

Comment: You can simplify the second line to: `tempThumb="${randomStr}_tempthumb"`.  You could even use: `tempThumb=$(date | md5sum | tr -d ' -')_tempthumb` to replace the first two lines.  That doesn't explain the problem, though.  Is `/bin/sh` a link to `bash` or to some other shell?  Does the script have a shebang line?  Does it list `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` or something else? (On Mac OS X, both `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` work as desired on: `tt="cs"; ls $HOME/soq/$tt*.c`, listing 3 files that start with `cs` and end `.c` in `$HOME/soq`.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler `ls -l /bin/sh 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 мар  1  2012 /bin/sh -> dash`

Comment: I don't understand logic. You just created a random name and trying to find a file with this name with `ls`. Obviously it will return nothing.

Comment: OK - time to investigate what `dash` does...but it appears to be subtly different from `bash` in this respect.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you actually solved my problem =) `ls /dev/shm/${tempThumb}*.jpg` Thanks.

Comment: Intriguing — glad to have helped.  I just downloaded and built `dash` 0.5.7-3 from Debian and built it on Mac OS X 10.8.4, and then used it on the `tt="cs"; ls $HOME/soq/$tt*.c` command and it worked fine as both `dash` and `sh`.  I think that using `${tempThumb}` is a good idea, but I don't have a good explanation for why you were running into the problem.  Maybe you have a non-default setting for the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the second line to:

```
tempThumb="${randomStr}_tempthumb"
```

You could even use:

```
tempThumb=$(date | md5sum | tr -d ' -')_tempthumb
```

to replace the first two lines.

That doesn't explain the problem, though. Is `/bin/sh` a link to `bash` or to some other shell? *[Answer: it is a link to `dash`.]*

Does the script have a shebang line? Does it list `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` or something else? (On Mac OS X, both `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh` work as desired on the script:

```
tt="cs"
ls $HOME/soq/$tt*.c
```

listing 3 files that start with `cs` and end `.c` in `$HOME/soq`.)

> [This] actually solved my problem — `ls /dev/shm/${tempThumb}*.jpg`

Intriguing — glad to have helped. I just downloaded and built dash 0.5.7-3 from Debian and built it on Mac OS X 10.8.4, and then used it on the two-line script above and it worked fine as both `dash` and `sh`. I think that using `${tempThumb}` is a good idea, but I don't have a good explanation for why you were running into the problem. Maybe you have a non-default setting for the shell?

Comment: My shebang line is `#!/bin/bash` =). "Maybe you have a non-default setting for the shell?" I don't think so, did play with bash setting at all.